# Where is the flash message in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so I have a delete users button

```
  <button id="delete" data="<%= user_path(@user) %>">Delete User</button>
```

which is using the jquery ui

```
   $("#delete").button();
```

and i want the clicking to delete the user so i have

```
   $("#delete").click(function(){
      if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
          var url = $(this).attr('data');
          $.post(url, {_method:'delete'}, null, "script");
          document.location = '<%= users_path %>';
          return false;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
   });
```

All works great but when the page refreshes I get no flash from my destroy action

```
def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted."
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this or restructure what i have done. I cant just use a link_to or button_to for styling purposes

Comment: Have you rendered flash messages anywhere in your views?  Setting a `flash` won't do anything if you aren't displaying them :/

Comment: its rendering but i assume the problem is that the jquery post is causing the issue

Comment: the flash message appears when i just use the link_to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash data only exists for the following request. It is being "eaten" by your AJAX postback.

When you `post` via `$.post`, you're actually making two requests; the `delete` requests follows the redirect and issues a `get` request to `users_path`. *That* request sees the flash data. When you then set your `document.location` to `users_path`, there is no longer any flash data to render.

You absolutely should not be handling this through hand-rolled AJAX. Allow your link to be clicked like a regular link and allow Rails' UJS to handle the post-back/confirm dialog. This should in *no way* impact your ability to style the link unless you're doing something very wrong.